# How do you represent the concept “rate per hour” visually or as an icon?

Tags: icon, conceptualization

I am trying to think of a good visual representation for "rate per hour" as in "this is the rate per hour that I am being charged at for this time" or "I am charging someone else at this rate per hour.

I thought of maybe thinking of other "per hour" things like a speed limit sign or a dollar sign, but that's too vague. I was hoping that there was a visual thing I can show in an icon to represent that concept. Or maybe just rate per unit or maybe rate per lead... something like that.

I also asked this question on [English language site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/484294/how-do-you-represent-the-concept-rate-per-hour-visually-or-as-an-icon) and was told to ask it here.

Comment: In what context? Are you going to hand your clients a little token with the icon on it instead of telling them you rate per hour? For example, if it's some sort of table where the rate accompanies the icon, the icon could be almost anything as long as you're able to connect it to the thing even if by learning. Like in an application of some kind you could learn by hovering over the icon to see what it represents. It could be even something like: `red $ = total` and `green $ = rate per hour` or 3 `$` symbols could represent the total to indicate there's more. It doesn't all have to be literal.

Comment: Why not just say "RPH", like MPH? Or "$/hr" as the answer on your English.SE post suggests? Why does it need to be an icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mix betweeen time and money:

[image]

<sub>Source [www.shareicon.net](https://www.shareicon.net/sand-clock-business-bills-money-dollars-stacked-stack-time-startup-icons-808080)</sub>

[image]

<sub>Source [www.iconfinder.net](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/4040396/alarm_clock_dollar_money_time_time_is_money_icon)</sub>

Comment: I like that clock with $ symbol

Answer (score 1):

Quick thought loosely based on the Entypo+ iconography

[image: rate per hour]